# what font face of clock on lock screen of iPhone (iOS 9)

Tags: ios9

What font face and font size of time on lock screen in iOS 9?
Is it Safransico font or HelveticaNeue-UltraLight?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IOS 9 is using San Francisco as its default font

Source: https://developer.apple.com/fonts/